# Direction of magnetic flux of mutual inductance where coupling coefficient is almost 1

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism, homework, magnetic-flux

I've drawn the below diagram of the circuit.

[image]

We will handle the system as the switch is closed .

The coupling coefficient of the system is almost 1

I assumed \$~ L_{1} ,L_{2},M ~\$  are all  positive real numbers  .

The book showed me the below equations.

$$  L_{1} \frac{  dI_{1}  }{  dt  } +M \frac{  dI_{2}  }{  dt  }+R_{1}I_{1} =E  \tag{1}  $$

$$  L_{2} \frac{  dI_{2}  }{  dt  } +M \frac{  dI_{1}  }{  dt  }+R_{2}I_{2} =0  \tag{2}  $$

What I thought for understand the above 2 equations are as below .

Firstly I focused on the left side circuit .

$$ \Phi_{1} :=\text{magnetic flux at coil1 made by } ~I_{1}~\text{only}  $$

$$  \Phi_{2} :=\text{magnetic flux made at coil2 by } ~ \Phi_{1}  ~ $$

As I apply KVL .

$$  \underbrace{L_{1} \frac{  dI_{1}  }{  dt  }}_\text{voltage drop}  + \underbrace{M \frac{  dI_{2}  }{  dt  }}_\text{why voltage drop?}  + \underbrace{R_{1}I_{1}}_\text{voltage drop}  - \underbrace{E}_\text{voltage rise}  =  0  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{Transformed eqn1}  $$

\$~ \Phi_{1}  ~\$ makes a direction of loop of clockwise.

Since \$~ \Phi_{1}  ~\$  enters coil2 from top to bottom , \$~ \Phi_{2}  ~\$ should flows from bottom to top . Then the top side endpoint of coil2 takes higher potential and the bottom endpoint takes a lower potential .  Hence the symbol of direction of \$~ I_{2} ~\$ in the diagram is adequate .

\$~ \Phi_{2}  ~\$ makes a direction of coutnerclockwise.

$$  \Phi_{1,2} :=\text{magnetic flux made at coil1 by } ~ \Phi_{2}    $$

The direction of \$~ \Phi_{1,2}  ~\$ is clockwise.

The top side endpoint of the coil1 takes a higher potential and the lower endpoint takes a lower potential.

So I think the negative sign should be attached to \$~ M \frac{  dI_{2}  }{  dt  } ~\$ to make an equation of KVL of left side circuit.

Where I've made (a) mistake(s)?

Comment: Draw an equivalent transformer circuit.

Comment: With the direction of currents as shown in your diagram, M will be negative.

Comment: Start from a conservation of energy consideration : the secondary circuit has no power source so it can only subtract energy from the primary. You will see that with the current convention you chose for the circuit, that implies M -ve as Andy says.